# Prove $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|^2}$ is in $S(R^n)$ and $L^p(R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis

My idea is to prove if the function is in $S(R^n)$ so because $S(R^n)$ is dense in $L^p(R^n)$ automatically $f$ is in $L^p(R^n)$

$S(R^n)=\{f\in C^\infty(R^n): sup_{x \in R^n} (1+|x|)^N |\partial^\alpha f|<\infty, \forall \alpha \in Z^n_+, \forall N \in Z_+    \}$.

If I consider $\partial_j(f)=\frac{-2x_j}{(1+|x|^2)^2}$ and $\frac{2|x_j|}{(1+|x|^2)^2}(1+|x|)^N$ dont't converges to zero for $|x|\rightarrow \infty$ if $N \ge5$ so $f\notin S(R^n)$?

Comment: The function clearly isn't in $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

For example, because $(1+|x|^2)\times f(x)=(1+|x|)^2\times\frac{1}{1+|x|^2}=1$ does not converge to $0$ when $|x|$ goes to  $+\infty$.

Comment: For the convergence in $L^p(R^n)$ have I to study different values of p?

Comment: In general, $\int (1+|x|^2)^{-s/2}\,dx$ converges if and only if $s>n$. [Raymond, Elementary introduction to theory of pseudodifferential operators, page 5, Lemma 1.3]
In your case, $\int (1+|x|^2)^{-p}\,dx$ converges if and only if $p>n/2$

Answer (score 1):

For the integrability in $L^p(R^n)$ :

$\int_{R^n} (\frac{1}{1+|x|^2})^p dx \le \int_{R^n}\frac{1}{|x|^{2p}}dx$

but there are problems of integration near zero and to infinite